# Calculate "u" in camera coordinates glulookat

Tags: math, graphics, geometry, glut, transformation

In calculating camera coordinates from world coordinates, how do we calculate u coordinate? I know it is normal(cross(up, zaxis)) but i am not able to get the logic/ maths behind it.

Comment: What's 'u' coordinate. Cross Product yields a vector that's orthogonal to the two vectors you're multiplying. Whats 'logic' is it that you're not able to understand. Need more info.

Comment: like why do we take cross product of up and zaxis?

Comment: Like I said, cross product yields a vector that's orthogonal to the two vectors. If you have three mutually orthogonal vectors, you've just defined the camera's (or any object's) coordinate space. If that's is not clear, I think, you should go back to reading more about 3d graphics rendering pipeline.